# Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier memoCell error

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let row=animals[indexPath.row]
  let cellIdentifier = "memoCell"
  let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MemoCellTableViewCell
  print(cell)
  print("mmmmmmm")
  print(cell.subject)
  cell.name?.text="aaa"
  return cell
}
```

I'm unable to set value to label, because I have an error saying:

> 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

So, I added `tableView.register(MemoCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "memoCell")`. Then, the problem is that I can't set a value to `cell.name` because `cell.name` is nil.

Comment: If `cell.name` is `nil`, you need to connect the outlet in your cell in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

First check that your outlet to the cell.name is connected perfectly then you can try by updating your method in below manner,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let row=animals[indexPath.row]
        let cellIdentifier = "memoCell"
        var cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MemoCellTableViewCell

        if cell == nil {

            cell = MemoCellTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }

        print(cell)
        print("mmmmmmm")
        print(cell.subject)
        cell.name?.text="aaa"
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove this methods

```
tableView.register(MemoCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "memoCell")
```

because your cell is in storyboard so you don't require this method, if you are using `tableviewCell XIB` then you can use this.

And in your `MemoCellTableViewCell.swift` file, create or connect all require outlet using storyboard and then try again. It should resolve issue, otherwise let me know.

Comment: here's my code...I really don't know why it's not working. code is really simple. please could you check sourcecode??? 
really appreciated it.